# In a directive, handle calls to a user defined method name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to allow the user to give a method name to a directive, let the directive create that method on the `scope`, and then handle calls to that method?

So, first I let the user define a method name `HELLO`, and then I let the user call `HELLO` from elsewhere (still in the same scope)

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div mydirective="" mydirective-data="MyJson" mydirective-fx="HELLO" />
    <button ng-click="HELLO()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Internally, the directive should see the `HELLO` and map it to its own method.  In the directive, I am looking at the method name being passed in and assigning it

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: {
           data: '=mydirectiveData',
           fx: '=mydirectiveFx'
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.fx = function () { console.log(scope.data); } ;
             }
         }
       }
    );
```

as you can see, I am assigning `scope.fx`, which should be `HELLO`, to a function which should read `scope.data`, defined in the controller.

Attempting this does not do anything nor does it throw an error. It makes me wonder if I am doing this the wrong way.

For clarity, I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIZYQV?p=preview).  Remember to open the console.

Comment: Why are you using a directive for this? It seems like a job for the controller. Your directive creates it's own scope and hides any function created internally from your button.

Comment: Basically, the directive has a method that the user needs to invoke, but instead of telling the user to call `MyFunctionName`, I'd like the user to define the method name. The directive does a lot of DOM manipulation and this is a reusable piece of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@` instead of `=` then `scope[scope.fx]` to create the property:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       data: '=mydirectiveData',
       fx: '@mydirectiveFx'
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope[scope.fx] = function () { console.log(scope.data); };
      }
     }
   }
);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/a2c14O?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! The `scope[scope.fx]` was the crucial bit, can you explain a bit more what's happening here?

Comment: Also I just realized this doesn't work when I switch back to Angular 1.0.8.  Is this impossible to achieve in the current stable version?

Comment: Unfortunately for 1.0.8, I could only accomplish what you did by removing the isolate scope, then using: `scope[attrs.mydirectiveFx] = function () { console.log(scope[attrs.mydirectiveData]); };`  Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3keD8y?p=preview

Comment: It seems that before 1.1.3 the attrs are not available on the scope until after the link phase. If you still want to use an isolate scope you can wrap it in a `$watch`: `scope.$watch('fx', function(fx) { scope[fx] = ... });`